# Want to download pdf and display it on same time on webview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to download one pdf and while downloading i wanted to show its preview or displayed the some part of pdf which was downloaded till that time on webview

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
  UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)]; //whatever size you want

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your url for pdf here"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it is showing pdf after completion of download.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can try the GCD

When you are downloading pdf, you can show the preview in webview.It does downloading and showing preview simultaneously.

For this GCD is good one to use.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ 
    // Do the back ground process
    ......Downloading the coding of pdf here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    // Update the UI here
    .....Do the webview coding
    });
});
```

> **Global Queue**
>
> Asynchronous task will be performed here.
>       It does not wait.
>       Asynchronous function does not block the current thread of execution from proceeding on to the next function.
>
> **Main Queue**
>
> We must always access UI Kit classes on the main thread.

[Ray wanderlich example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1)

Comment: I am downloading pdf using NSURLConnection methods, suppose my pdf size is 10mb and and initially i got 2 mb data in didReceiveData method so i want to display pdf with that much of data.

Comment: Why do you want to get pdf in much data(mb size)?

Comment: its just for example, i just want while downloading pdf user will not stuck on that screen for long time.

Comment: If  you use your code in global and main queue of GCD you won't be in stuck.

Comment: @SachinAmrale : If you will download it asynchronously then definitely you will not stuck!!!

Comment: @user3182143 Thanks.